# Show that $\|T\|=\|T^*\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $T:H \to H$ be a bounded linear transformation between Hilbert spaces. Let $T^*$ be the adjoint of T. Show that $\|T\|=\|T^*\|$.

I know that $\langle Tx,y\rangle=\langle x,T^*y\rangle$, but I don't know how to use it to prove $\|T\|=\|T^*\|$.

Comment: I know that $\|T\| = \sup_{\substack{x \in H \\ \|x\|=1}} | \langle Tx, x\rangle|$

Comment: I deleted my comment as it overlaps Aweygan's answer. :) See below for the detail to come.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Using the CBS inequality, you can obtain
$$\|T\|=\sup\{|\langle Tx,y\rangle|:x,y\in H, \|x\|\leq1,\|y\|\leq1\}$$
from which the result follows rather quickly.

Comment: I would also like to mention that it can also be proved by elementary means if we restrict our interests only on Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks, I realized that after typing this.  Edit in progress.